# Trouble Including Externally Declared Enumeration - C Code

Tags: c, enums, header, header-files, enumeration

Update: The issue is resolved. Here is code that compiles properly.

```html
---instruction.h---
#ifndef INSTRUCTION_H
#define INSTRUCTION_H

typedef enum OPCODE {ADD = 0x20,ADDI = 0x8,SUB = 0x22,MULT = 0x18,BEQ = 0x4,LW = 0x23,SW = 0x2B} opcode;
/*opcode is OPCODEs alias*/
typedef struct INSTRUCTION {
    opcode op;
    int rs;
    int rt;
    int rd;
    int Imm;
} inst;
/*inst is INSTRUCTIONs alias*/
#endif // INSTRUCTION_H

---parser.c---
#include <stdio.h>
#include "instruction.h"
void parser(char *instruction)
{
    /*Parse character string into instruction components*/
    inst set1 = {LW,0,1,2,0};
    printf("parsing");
};

int main()
{
    char *instruction;
    instruction = NULL;
    parser(instruction);
};
/*pass in pointer for instruction being passed in*/
/*pointing to address of instruction being passed in*/
/*Parser return type is struct inst*/
```

I cannot seem to get my enumeration type "opcode" to be recognized in my main c file. I included the header file. I am fairly new to C, so haven't made much ground on the issue for some time now and wanted to see if anyone knew why I was getting the error messages below. My guess is the linking the header file is not working properly. Any help is much appreciated.[image]

```
---instruction.h----

#ifndef INSTRUCTION_H
#define INSTRUCTION_H

typedef enum {add = 32,addi = 8,sub = 34,mult = 24,beq = 4,lw = 35,sw = 43}opcode;
extern opcode oper;
typedef struct {
    opcode op;
    int rs;
    int rt;
    int rd;
    int Imm;
}inst;
#endif // INSTRUCTION_H

---Parser.c---

#include <stdio.h>
#include "instruction.h"
void parser(char *inst)
{
    /*Parse character string into instruction components*/
    struct inst{lw,0,1,2,0};

};

int main()
{
    char *instruction;
    instruction = NULL;
    parser(instruction);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct inst{lw,0,1,2,0};
```

This looks like it's supposed to be a variable declaration, but I don't see a name for the variable. Try:

```
struct inst name_of_the_variable = {lw,0,1,2,0};
```

As a side note, `enum` values are global constants, so it's probably not a good idea to give them names like `lw` that can be confused for variables. Standard practice would be to use all-caps for the names and give them a prefix… say, `OPCODE_ADD`, `OPCODE_LW`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid variable definition:

```
struct inst{lw,0,1,2,0};
```

There's no `struct inst` defined, only `inst`, there's no variable name, and you need `=` to use an initializer.  To create a variable of this type an initialize it, you need:

```
inst myinst = {lw,0,1,2,0};
```

Also, your function has a parameter named `inst` which masks the type `inst`.  You need to give it a different name:

```
void parser(char *instruction)
```

Comment: @CormacKennedy Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.